# Haskell algorithm to find all possible Beta reductions

Tags: algorithm, haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that would print all available beta reductions for a given expression.

I know I will need a matching pattern cases to see if item is reducible and if not then the three cases cases for variable, lambda and application. I have custom type for these defined as follows:

```
data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term
  deriving Show
```

Previously I've implemented following methods:

the functionality of the given methods is as follows:

- Merge
- Rename renames to avoid variable capturing
- Substitution reducing the expression
- fresh gives a new variable to which was not previously used
- used returns all used variables for given expression

So far everything works well, however, the function for returning all possible beta reductions is where I'm lost. I've tried to define the four case matching pattern as shown below, however I'm struggling with the definition of the redex case (especially looking into redex for other redex) and the operations which need to take place in the beta method.:

```
beta :: Term -> [Term]
beta (Variable var) = 
beta (Lambda var term) = 
beta (Apply term1 term2)
```

I now don't know how to proceed here in order to get all available reductions. The outcome should be:

```
*Main> Apply (x y)
(\a. \x. (\y. a) x b) (\f. \x. f x)
*Main> beta it
[\c. (\b. \f. \x. f x) c b,(\a. \x. a b) (\f. \x. f x)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an informal description, as a hint.

```
beta :: Term -> [Term]
beta (Variable var) = ...
```

Variables don't beta-reduce, so this case should be easy.

```
beta (Lambda var term) = ...
```

Lambdas only reduce if their body reduces. Start with recursing on `term`.

```
beta (Apply term1 term2) = ...
```

This is the complex part: we have three subcases here.

- If `term1` reduces, the whole application reduces accordingly.
- If `term2` reduces, the whole application reduces accordingly.
- If `term1` happens to be a lambda, you have found a redex. You can substitute the abstracted variables in the lambda body with `term2`.

The whole code could follow this shape:

```
beta :: Term -> [Term]
beta (Variable var) = ...
beta (Lambda var term) = ...
beta (Apply term1 term2) = term1Moves ++ term2Moves ++ redexMoves
   where
   term1Moves = ...
   term2Moves = ...
   redexMoves = case term1 of
      Lambda var term -> ...
      _               -> []        -- no further moves
```

List comprehensions could be convenient to use.

---

Taking a part of the code the OP posted, and adding a few more hints, we get:

```
beta :: Term -> [Term]
beta (Variable var) = ...
beta (Lambda var term) = ...
beta (Apply term1 term2) = term1Moves ++ term2Moves ++ redexMoves
   where
   term1Moves = [ Apply term1' term2 | term1' <- beta term1 ]
   term2Moves = ...
   redexMoves = case term1 of
      Lambda var body -> [substitute var term2 body]  -- don't recurse here
      _               -> []        -- no further moves
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It has helped me with the recognition part however I still seem to be struggling to get the parsing part correct. I suppose beta (Lambda var term) = beta term however the further logic is still not clear enough. Could you provide the solution to the problem? I've been trying for an hour now not getting anywhere close.

Comment: @gaming4mining, `beta term` is the reduced body, but you need to put the reduced body back in the lambda it came from, i.e. `Lambda var (beta term)`.   Also don't give up so easily, an hour is not that much time!  Every little step is teaching you something you can use again someday

Comment: I don't seem to be getting any further after a day of trying. I've implemented the Lambda case as you've suggested, that seems to be working fine. However for the third case I'm still lost. I've tried: `(Apply left right) = case left of
    Lambda var body  -> (substitute var (normal right) body)
    otherwise -> Apply (normal left) (normal right)`

But that just yielded more errors, than solutions. Could you please elaborate on the last case?

Comment: @gaming4mining See the edit for more hints.

Comment: @chi Thanks a lot for updated answer. I think I'm very close to the actual solution, however it seems like it still doesn't compile due to the Type mismatch. Could you please take a look into the edit to see what am I missing? I thought I went by the hints you've posted but still there is the last bit missing.

Comment: @gaming4mining The lambda case must return a list, not a single term. You should use a list comprehension a in term1Moves. Also, your term2Moves compiles but is wrong -- double check that.

Comment: @chi Yeh I've tried to make it return a list as per `beta (Lambda var term) = [Lambda var (beta term)]` but then the pattern matching threw the error about pattern not being matched properly.

Comment: I seem to be missing something, if I return a list, then the recursive calls are expecting list as well however, the pattern matching doesn't have one, thus it doesn't compile. What am I missing here?

Comment: @gaming4mining `Lambda var (beta term)` is wrong, since `beta term` is a list, not a term. Repeating my suggestion: you should use a list comprehension as in term1Moves. Something like `[Lambda var t | ..... ]`.

Comment: Yes, you were right,  I was thinking I need to pattern match the list which was the merit of my issues. Thank you for all the guidance I've finally arrived at the solution.